# Android and Google Play: how to get / getting provider tag data?

Tags: java, android, google-play

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html:

```
<provider android:authorities="list"
          android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
          android:exported=["true" | "false"]
          android:grantUriPermissions=["true" | "false"]
          android:icon="drawable resource"
          android:initOrder="integer"
          android:label="string resource"
          android:multiprocess=["true" | "false"]
          android:name="string"
          android:permission="string"
          android:process="string"
          android:readPermission="string"
          android:syncable=["true" | "false"]
          android:writePermission="string" >
    . . .
</provider>
```

How can I use Java to get the android:xyz data?

Comment: Anything specific you want to fetch here .. ?

Comment: android:authorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't access that field, however you can use a string resource:

**values/strings.xml:**

```
<string name="my_authority">com.example.some_authority</string>
```

Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:authorities="@string/my_authority"
</provider>
```

And in your code:

```
getString(R.string.my_authority)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thanks... can it be in some other xml file or does it need to be in strings.xml specifically?

Comment: Hmm. I guess it's global. Interesting. (But, do you know if there's a way to make this local? like.... "bleh.xml@string/my_authority" or something, IDK.)

Comment: @Agamemnus why would you need that?

Comment: @Agamemnus if you could provide a use case (which would perhaps help me understand the problem), I may be able to help more. Atm it seems that you want to have the authority accessible only to the manifest and somewhere in your code, which is global access :)

Comment: Potential namespace issues, but not just for that string. Just want to know if the strings and integers in the ``/platforms/android/res/xml/`` directory are all global, all the time?